# VB.Net - Audio Files Album Arts

Tags: vb.net, audio, mp3, albumart, id3v2

Basically I'm despaired.

I've tried everything I've seen on every Google result concerning this problem.

I have a program that is very similar to WMP. It's using axWMP control to play songs and etc.

I've got many types of audio files, mp3, m4a, wma, etc. I've successfully coded something to get the tags: track#, title, album, artist, year. The only thing I can't seem to get correctly done is the album art.

The code I'm using only works for some mp3 files. Of course it's because I'm using UltraID3 and that would only work for mp3.

Here's the code:

```
                Dim MP3Tag As New UltraID3

            albumArt = Nothing

            Try
                MP3Tag.Read(path)
                Try
                    Dim pics = MP3Tag.ID3v2Tag.Frames.GetFrames(CommonMultipleInstanceID3v2FrameTypes.Picture)
                    albumArt = CType(pics(0), ID3v2PictureFrame).Picture
                Catch ex As Exception
                    'albumArt = FetchAlbumImage(j, path)
                End Try
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
```

But then I tried fetching the album art through the WMP control itself, just like I did for the rest of the tags :

```
    Function FetchAlbumArt(index As Integer, filePath As String) As Image

    FetchAlbumArt = Nothing

    Dim pic As WMPLib.IWMPMetadataPicture = Nothing

    Dim tWMP As New WindowsMediaPlayer

    tWMP.currentMedia = Me.WMP.currentPlaylist.Item(index)

    For i = 0 To tWMP.currentMedia.getAttributeCountByType("WM/Picture", "")
        Try
            pic = tWMP.currentMedia.getItemInfoByType("WM/Picture", "", i)
            Exit For
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(Err.Description)
        End Try
    Next

    If Not IsNothing(pic) Then

        Dim path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache)
        Dim fInfo, fInfos() As IO.FileInfo
        Dim dInfo As IO.DirectoryInfo

        dInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(path)
        fInfos = dInfo.GetFiles("*" & FindStringBeforeLastIndexOfChar(FindStringAfterLastIndexOfChar(pic.URL, "/"), ".", False) & "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

        For Each fInfo In fInfos
            If fInfo.Name Like "*" & FindStringBeforeLastIndexOfChar(FindStringAfterLastIndexOfChar(pic.URL, "/"), ".", False) & "*" Then
                System.IO.File.Copy(fInfo.FullName, dbFolderPath & "\temp.jpg", True)
            End If
        Next

        Dim albumArt As Image
        albumArt = Bitmap.FromFile(dbFolderPath & "\temp.jpg")

        FetchAlbumArt = albumArt

    End If

End Function
```

This function goes into the internet explorer temp folder and copy the image outside in order to use it. It works, but then again only for the same mp3 files.

I've read about the Apple Quick Time control I could use for m4a files, but I couldn't get anything out of it.

One thing that really bothers me is that it works for mp3 but not all of them.

The only clues I have to why it's not working are : "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index" on line MP3Tag.Read(path) above and "The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))" on line pic = tWMP.currentMedia.getItemInfoByType("WM/Picture", "", i) for whenever the file is a not working mp3 or other file format.

I know it's not impossible as WMP 12 itself displays the album arts for any file just fine.

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

WMP stores its album art in the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Media Player\Art Cache\LocalMLS` folder. The filenames of the JPEG files in this folder correspond to the [TrackingID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute of the WMP media items in the library.